# Is it possible to output from Html local storage to a .csv or similar?

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova, csv

Is this possible?

It has to be done using HTML5, CSS, and Javascript. I am using Phonegap.

I have looked through countless forums and websites and understand there is a file api in phonegap but even if I am able to get the information into a file using this api will I be able to extract this file on to a pc for example?

At the moment I am able to store the data I need to in localStorage.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Do you mean, like this? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: Yes, so if I used the file api described there, when I have the data I need in a file is there anyway to export this file or access this file through a pc/mac (e.g. explorer, finder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is possible to output .csv content from local storage to a file, but as this is in a sandboxed environment within the browser it is not possible to access the location of the file in which this information is stored, and access that file as if it were a .csv file.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to loop through all your `localStorage` and set each item... something like below:

```
var compositeCSV = "";
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  compositeCSV += localStorage[i] + "|";
}
```

However, that won't work - you can't iterate through `localStorage` like that. You'll need to get each one seperately.

In CSV a comma `,` is a new "cell" and a pipe `|` is a new row.

Comment: So if I have the data I need in the compositeCSV varialble. How do I then get this out of the phonegap app and into a file readable on windows/mac?

Comment: PhoneGap runs on a mobile, so you would have to Sync the data on a server or send it somewhere to pick it up on the Windows/Mac/Linux box. You can save files to persistent storage with PhoneGap, but that's another question ;)

Comment: So with persistant storage this would be through the file api?

Comment: That's correct, here is the File Writer API: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter

Comment: Is it possible to write to a file using persistant storage and then access this through Windows/Mac/Linux box? This is what I was originally hoping to do.

Comment: The only way I can see to do this would be to write the file then sync it on a server... :( (of course, I may be wrong!)